# Setting similar formulas for many cells

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am using below code to find Max value. This code found on web search. And made changes according to me as below.

```
Sub OPTION_MAX()
ActiveSheet.Range("BU2").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2:BC$3000=$BM2,BE$2:BE$3000))"
ActiveSheet.Range("BU3").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2:BC$3000=$BM3,BE$2:BE$3000))"
ActiveSheet.Range("BU4").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2:BC$3000=$BM4,BE$2:BE$3000))"
ActiveSheet.Range("BU5").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2:BC$3000=$BM5,BE$2:BE$3000))"
ActiveSheet.Range("BU6").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2:BC$3000=$BM6,BE$2:BE$3000))" 
End Sub
```

The lines are upto 3000 rows, very lengthy though. Could someone help me out to shorten this code.

Comment: So, for BU2 through BU3000, you're setting the formula to include the cell in column BM on that row?

Comment: Use a loop? `For i As Integer = 1 To 3000`

Comment: garryp...........as I am not vba programmer, could you please help, how to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("BU2:BU3000").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(R2C55:R3000C55=RC55,R2C57:R3000C57))"
```

Comment: Ralph............made some changes in your above code i.e. RC65 in place RC55. Yes I am getting correct answer in cell BU2 but further same answer generating till BU3000

Comment: That's probably because you got the formula wrong. The formula you are implementing does not make much sense because `ActiveSheet.Range("BU2").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2:BC$3000=$BM2,BE$2:BE$3000))"` is equal to `ActiveSheet.Range("BU2").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(BC$2=$BM2,BE$2:BE$3000))"`. But your question was not about the formula but about how to get the formula into 3000 rows. I think that is solved. Right? If so, please mark this question as answered.